# Vue Js binding 2 values to a tag href

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm beginner on Vue js. I'm facing an issue where I have to update two values while rendering.

```
<ul class="category-list">
    <li v-for="category in categories">
        <a v-bind:href="location/category.slug/all" v-text="category.name"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My javascript file

```
new Vue({
    el : '#example',

    data : {
        location:   'new-york',
        categories: [],
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('parent-categories').then((response) => {
            this.categories = response.data;
        });
    },
});
```

Ajax Response

```
[{"name":"Default Category","slug":"default-category"},{"name":"Main Category","slug":"main-category"}]
```

Here I wanted to build url structure like location/category-slug/all ie,

http://myapp.com/new-york/default-category/all

How to achieve this?

Comment: The value you provide inside `v-bind:href` should be valid javascript expressions, Try `v-bind:href='"location/"+category.slug+"/all"'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out how to handle this situation after a long struggle. All I have to do is to create a method that generates URL for me.

JS

```
new Vue({
    el : '#example',

    data : {
        location:   'new-york',
        categories: [],
    },
    methods: {
       slug: function (category) {
            return this.location+'/'+category.slug+'/all';
        }

    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('parent-categories').then((response) => {
            this.categories = response.data;
        });
    },
});
```

Html

```
<div id="example">
     <h3>Services</h3>
     <ul class="category-list">
         <li v-for="category in categories">
             <a :href="slug(category)" v-text="category.name"></a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```